# Синхронизация автономных баз данных

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

На работе стоит задача вести базу данных на автономных компьютерах (т.е. все АРМы не подключены по ЛВС). Задача приложения - это автоматизация делопроизводства отдела. На всех АРМах предполагается иметь идентичные БД, а синхронизацию осуществлять с помощью съемного носителя информации(флэшка или оптический диск). Рассматривал подходы Framework Sync, но как я понял это не подойдет, так как она делает снимок БД, что влечет большими объемами перекидывания информации. Так же испытал стандартную программу bcp с помощью запросов к БД по схеме выгружаю данные в xml и записываю в необходимую БД, но проблема возникает если строка от клиента 1 имеет значения ФИО, то когда клиент 2 принес те же значения только ФИ, то результат будет последним (но это не правильно, так как должно записать ФИ, а от клиента 1 значение О должен оставить без изменений). Направьте в нужное направление, может где-то неправильно разобрался или есть другие подходы в решение синхронизации.

Comment: Я думаю вам надо на флэшку скидывать историю событий и при подключении к АРМ разбирать историю в соответствии с определенными правилами, а потом информ. вносить в локальную БД. И в определенные промежутки времени проводить индексирование БД. Т.е. берется БД и сравнивается, если есть отличия вручную их разрешаете или автоматически по определенному алгоритму

Comment: Спасибо буду думать!

Comment: @AlexsandrTer, оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.